# Git merge: accept theirs for multiple conflicts

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm trying to merge a git branch (test-development) back into master. There are lots of merge conflicts but I want as many as possible to be resolved via --theirs. Is there a way to tell git to merge with --theirs in bulk?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This will do it (does not just resolve the conflicts but takes their version of the files) if you're mid-merge:

```
git merge test-development
# Automatic merge failed, a bunch of conflicts!
git checkout --theirs ./path
git add ./path
git commit
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a bunch of variations to no avail. `[sekingerg@centos-sekinger master2]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
[sekingerg@centos-sekinger master2]$ git branch
* master
[sekingerg@centos-sekinger master2]$ git checkout --theirs .
[sekingerg@centos-sekinger master2]$ git add .
[sekingerg@centos-sekinger master2]$ git commit
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
[sekingerg@centos-sekinger master2]$`

Comment: Well, you need to actually do the merge -- I edited the merge command into my answer.

Comment: Also: this will bring all of the changes from `test-development` that *don't* conflict into `master`, and accept `test-development`'s version over `master`'s for any that conflict. Is that what you want, or do you want everything to look like `test-development` unconditionally, whever it conflicts or not?

Comment: This really helped. As it turned out, it was only half my problem. I use VitrualBox on a windows machine and have my git repo on a shared drive which means it's really on a NTFS partition. We've had a number of file renames where only case was changed in the filenames. Doing this over the shared folder proved to be extremely problematic. I cloned the master onto a ext4 partition and all of the odd errors I was seeing are gone.

Comment: WARNING: this will silently overwrite any changes in your local workspace, even in files that are not conflicted.

Comment: Additional tip: You can do this for multiple files like this: `git checkout --theirs ./*` and `git add ./*`

Comment: Anyway to update the answer w/ what to do if you're not mid merge?  Ie from scratch?  Just to make this a great reference...

Comment: @Spenhouet legend!

Comment: @Spenhouet `grep -lr '<<<<<<<' . | xargs git checkout --theirs && git add --all` seems like a better option

Comment: I get an error with multiple files that have been removed, "does not have their version". How can I get around this?