# Git how to merge conflict if want to use source or destination file only

Tags: git, git-merge

When I am doing megring from source to destination branch, Lets say I got conflict in 5 files and I am sure I want to use source or destination  branch, 
how to do this quickly.

In perforce i use the option accept target or accept source, to resolve merging conflict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git resolve conflict using --ours/--theirs for all files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743769/git-resolve-conflict-using-ours-theirs-for-all-files)

Comment: possibly a duplicate of <br>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544305/git-merge-accept-theirs-for-multiple-conflicts

Comment: It worked but,  What is the other solution for that, I mean lets say I want to merge commit C1  to C15 But I would like to avoid commit C12,C9 Also while merging, I know in advance commit C12, C9 will do some merging conflict, And don't want to see the merging conflict